# retrieve the method from auth.services.ts to login.component.ts in json

Tags: json, angular, components

app/auth/auth.services.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {User} from './user';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  result: any; 

  constructor(private router: Router, private _http: Http) {}


  getUsers() {

    return this._http.get('/api/users').map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }
}
```

http://localhost:3000/api/users :

```
{"status":200,"data":[{"_id":"5a63f4da17fc7e9e5548da70","name":"Jonson Doeal"},{"_id":"5a63faf417fc7e9e5548da71","name":"Jonson Bol"},{"_id":"5a64f44de87b3e2f80437c6b","name":"aaaa"}],"message":null}
```

I would like to retrieve data in json from the getUsers method  so that I cancompare values

```
 for () {
   if (json_value_name == this.temp) {
   }
 }
```

login.component.ts:

```
import {AuthService} from './../auth/auth.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(  
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit() {

      this.authService.getUsers();
      console.log('this.authService.getUsers() ' + JSON.stringify(this.authService.getUsers()));
    }
}
```

the console returns:

```
this.authService.getUsers(){"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}}
```

I would like it to return in this form:

```
{"status":200,"data":[{"_id":"5a63f4da17fc7e9e5548da70","name":"Jonson Doeal"},{"_id":"5a63faf417fc7e9e5548da71","name":"Jonson Bol"},{"_id":"5a64f44de87b3e2f80437c6b","name":"aaaa"}],"message":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `subscribe`

```
onSubmit() {

this.authService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data)});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would something like this:

```
private myData: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  myData = this.authService.getUsers();
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log('this.authService.getUsers() ' + JSON.stringify(myData));
}
```

Comment: this.myData = this.authService.getUsers();  => Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving is the expected result from that method call. The http calls in angular return observables. That means you need to subscribe to what you are returning. Depending on what you are trying to do you may want to restructure your service or component to fully utilize the pattern.

In order to print your data try this in your component:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.authService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(`users ${data}`)
  });
}
```

Hopefully this can get you started on using observables.